# Can you get cartel coins from the security key as a prefered player?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Just wondering if you subscribe and activate a security key you get 100 cartel coins per month.
Do you keep getting the cartel coins if you stop your subscription and become a preferred player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below has changed — now any player can add a Security Key and get coins.  See [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/swtor/comments/3dn2hj/can_f2p_get_free_cartel_coins_for_security_key/).

---

Yes you can, as long as you are subbed when you add it (as you mention).  I've had several players tell me this worked for them, but please also see [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/swtor/comments/1wul13/do_prefferred_players_get_free_cartel_coins/) for independent confirmation.

Comment: Thx, does it have to be a security key with the app?

Comment: @Vahx The physical key should work just fine, but it is no longer sold by EA/BioWare.

Comment: @Vahx You can also use WinAuth instead of the Smartphone App